# transforming cartesian to polar coordinates?

Tags: polar-coordinates

Transform the given polar equation to rectangular coordinates, and identify the curve represented.
$$r=\frac{5}{3\sin\theta-4\cos\theta}$$
Any tips? The first thing I tried was replace $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ with $y/r$ and $x/r$ respectively. Then what do I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$3r\sin \theta - 4r\cos\theta=5$$

Comment: wow. thanks. :)

Comment: I did it, but one more question (now im doing anohther problem) if I get rcos^2teta is that the same as x^2?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask that as a separate question.